# Language data coming as ??? after build in java application

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have the requirement to display data in my application based on the data available in a translation look up map which is filled from a JSON file previously saved. When I run my application in eclipse it is reading the file fine a displaying the data in the different languages I want; the Text file encoding of the project is "UTF-8". But after I build my application using the build.xml given below.

```
<project name="DRIS" default="create_jar">
<path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib/"/>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/"/>
  </path>
<target name="create_jar">
    <tstamp>
          <format property="DSTAMP" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm aa"/>
      </tstamp>
    <jar destfile="LDC_MCM.jar">
        <zipfileset dir="bin" prefix=""/>               
        <zipfileset src="lib\obcsclient.jar"/>
        <zipfileset src="lib\comm.jar"/>
        <zipfileset src="lib\obcsclientfrmk.jar"/>
        <zipfileset src="lib\commons-net-ntp.jar"/>
        <zipfileset src="lib\org.json.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Java-Version" value="${java.version} "/>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.ars.ldcmcm.Launcher"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="comm.jar jmf.jar mediaplayer.jar obcsclient.jar obcsclientfrmk.jar sound.jar commons-net-ntp.jar"/>
            <attribute name="Application-Name" value="LDC_MCM"/>
            <attribute name="Application-Version" value="1.85.106.120"/>
            <attribute name="Application-Vendor" value="ARS Software Engineering Pvt. Ltd"/>
            <attribute name="Application-built-on" value="${DSTAMP}" /> 
            <attribute name="Application-built-by" value="${user.name}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Then I run my application jar it show the data in other languages as ???. I'm not that familiar with ant. My best assumption would be that it might be because the UTF-8 encoding is not specified in the ANT, if so can someone please advice me on where I should specify my encoding in the above xml file. If my assumption is wrong can someone help me in solving this issue.

This is the piece of code that I use to read the data from the json file

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(
                              new FileInputStream(config.getStringValue("TRANSLOOKUP_FOLDER")
                                    + "\\"
                                    + config.getStringValue("TRANSLOOKUP_FILENAME")), "UTF8"));
        String str = "";
        in.mark(1);
        if(in.read() != '\uFEFF') {
            in.reset();
        }
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonStr.append(str);
        }
        in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very first line of the ant file, try to put

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

But I don't know if that will solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry this will not solve my problem, and I'm not sure if the file encoding while building is the issue

Comment: Is the json file being found by your application outside Eclipse?